# Get the RAM type detail description from WMI

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, wmi, wmic

I use the following command: `wmic path Win32_PhysicalMemory get TypeDetail` to get the type detail value. It returns: `16512`. From the Microsoft docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-physicalmemory

Only the following values are available:

> Reserved (1) Other (2) Unknown (4) Fast-paged (8) Static column (16)
> Pseudo-static (32) RAMBUS (64) Synchronous (128) CMOS (256) EDO (512)
> Window DRAM (1024) Cache DRAM (2048) Non-volatile (4096) Nonvolatile

But there is no description for value: `16512`. So, my question is: how to get the description for this value? Thanks.

Comment: [wmic is highly outdated. You should parse the SMBIOS table yourself for reliable results](https://superuser.com/a/1540441/241386)

Comment: @phuclv

Hello! I use `wmic` only for testing `WMI` values. I use `WMI` queries to get the data in my app. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per Microsoft documentation it appears that the value comes from SMBIOS information. If we break down the value `16512` to bits, we'll see that bits 7 and 14 are set. From [SMBIOS spec](https://www.dmtf.org/sites/default/files/standards/documents/DSP0134_2.7.1.pdf), section **7.18.3 Memory Device — Type Detail**, we can see that bit 7 indicates `Synchronous` and bit 14 indicates `Unbuffered (unregistered)`.

Comment: I have checked the `SMBIOS Reference Specification`. So, in my case it means both the Synchronous and Unbuffered (unregistered)? Thank you.

Comment: I suppose it is